# How to update page content after success post without page refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, page-refresh

I have a MVC application and this is my ajax code. I want that my page content update auto without page refresh after success.I saw many article, but I cant find anything useful for me. I have a JStree in which I want to create a new node after success node name automatically update in tree without refresh page.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {                  
                    var check = $(".newName").val();                   
                    if (check != "") {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("EditUserProfile", "Home")',
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            data:{ folder:Name,subId:id},
                            success: function (data) {

                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your page content without refresh:

1. Make sure your method **EditUserProfile** in Home controller has enough parameters and they have the same name with your ajax method. In this case, they are : **folder** and **subId**.
2. Remove `window.location.reload();`and get the `data.result` to check if the response success or not.
3. Please see my code:

**View**

`$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditUserProfile", "Home")',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        folder: Name,
        subId: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.result == true) // or something
        {
            // success
        } else {
            // fail
        }
    }
});`

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult EditUserProfile(string folder, string subId) {
    // do something

    return Json(new {
        result = true; // false or anything else
    });
}
```

The reason is you do nothing with data display on your html. Ajax just help you to call the method in Controller but not edit the current display data for you.

All you have to do:

- Assign the row with contains your data with an id
- Use Jquery to update the content of that row after Ajax return a success value.

Comment: ajax call is success but my page content is not updating .when i refresh page using f5 then page content are updating.

Comment: i m week in Jquery. Can you tell me how to update the content of the row after Ajax return a success value. It is very helpful for me.

Comment: You can see how to create a simple CRUD application using MVC with Ajax here : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-in-asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-and-bootstrap/ . Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

try with jquery `load()`,

```
$('#treeDivBlock').load(" #treeDivBlock", function() { 
     $(this).children().unwrap();
});
```

Comment: its is not Working